# Testing http rest APIs that have long running queries that are polled for status

Tags: performance, api, rest, testing, performance-testing

I'm struggling to find a framework to help me test the performance of a service I am writing, that has a long running process it fronts. A simplified description of the service is:

1. POST data to the service /start endpoint, it returns a token.
2. GET the status of the action at /status/{token}, poll this until it returns a status of completed.
3. GET the results from /result/{token}.

I've dabbled with Locust.io, which is fine for measuring the responsiveness of the API, but does little for measuring the overall end to end performance. What I would really like to do is measure how long all three steps take to complete, particularly when I run many in parallel etc. I should imagine my service back end falls over far sooner than the rest API does.

Can anyone recommend any tools / libraries / frameworks I can use to measure this please? I would like to integrate it with my build pipeline so I can measure performance as code is changed.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option I can think of is going for [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), it provides [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) which generates an additional "transaction" holding its children cumulative response time (along with other [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html))

"Polling" can be implemented using [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

Example test plan outline with results:

[image]